# How to integrate dialogflow chatbot with Microsoft Teams?

Tags: node.js, botframework, dialogflow-es, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am a newbie to chatbots, and built one agent in dialogflow and written a node server to connect it with my custom UI. Now my next requirement is to integrate this bot with my Microsoft Teams Channel.

For what I have searched there seem to be similar steps being followed as with skype but those didn't make sense to me. Though I am not really clear about it, if anyone can give a step wise points to follow to do the same, it will be great help.

Also just to be clear, can someone confirm if it's really possible to integrate Google's dialogflow with Microsoft's Teams?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you link to the information you say you've seen about how to do this? Please have a look at this handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: yes, I tried doing it in skype manner (following this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/skype), but apparently we have to create a chatbot and register the app in azure first, my org account has AAD restrictions now trying to get those permissions now.

Comment: @KyleDelaney thanks for reply, can you confirm that...following above steps (after getting AAD permissions) if I can deploy the dialogflow bot to MS Teams as well..?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any official instructions explaining how to connect a Dialogflow bot to Teams, but Skype and Teams both communicate through the Azure Bot Service using the Bot Framework protocol. When a Dialogflow bot connects to Skype what it's really connecting to is the Azure Bot Service, so you should be able to follow the same instructions for any ABS channel, Teams included.